# redirect user depending on location

Tags: php

I am getting the user's location from his IP address. What would be the best practice to redirect the user to preferrable language website only once? It has to be possible to pick another language and not be redirected again.

Comment: I hate getting redirected because some website assumes I prefer to have the site in the originating IP's language. What if I am just on vacation there? Please check http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales#answer

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Do you want to determine the language from the location (IP) of the user, or do you want the user to pick a language, and then stick to the same language once redirected?

Comment: Yeah, also I agree with Gordon. When I'm in Iceland (my native country) some websites assume I want Icelandic but I almost never want that. This feature can also be especially tricky for people who are in a country where they don't speak the native language, since they may have difficulty figuring out how to select English (or their native language). Just one thing to keep in mind... make sure that people can easily select English. :)

Comment: @HelgiHrafnGunnarsson it gets even worse when you are in a country with a different alphabet than the one you know.

Comment: Rather than basing on IP locating, why not use the client's browser Default Language setting? This information is passed in an HTTP header to your application (HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE), which can easily be accessed and processed in PHP... [See this](http://www.dyeager.org/post/2008/10/getting-browser-default-language-php), for example (the first link on Google for 'browser default language').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say store a cookie with location preference.